# Fade in/out multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

**[Here's the final version that works fine!](http://jsfiddle.net/KidStrong/qzNEf/7/)**

So, i have multiple divs, each containing a button to fade in another div, and fade out themselves. When i fade in one div, all the other divs (faded in by the button) shall fade out. Mabe difficult to understand, but [here is my FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KidStrong/qzNEf/4/)

Div 1 with button to fade-in div 2 (display:none;)

```
<div class="cnt" id="cnt-1">CONTENT 1<br>
    <div class="btn" id="btn-1">BUTTON 1</div>
</div>

<div class="cnt" id="cnt-2">CONTENT 2<br>
    <div class="btn" id="btn-2">BUTTON 2</div>
</div>
```

Div 3 with button to fade-in div 4 (display:none;)

```
<div class="cnt" id="cnt-3">CONTENT 3<br>
    <div class="btn" id="btn-3">BUTTON 3</div>
</div>

<div class="cnt" id="cnt-4">CONTENT 4<br>
    <div class="btn" id="btn-4">BUTTON 4</div>
</div>
```

and so on...

JS to fade-out 1 and fade-in 2

```
$('#btn-1').click(function(e){    
    $('#cnt-1, #cnt-4, #cnt6').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#cnt-2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn-2').click(function(e){    
    $('#cnt-2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#cnt-1, #cnt-3, #cnt-5').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

As you can see, the divs don't fade at the same time and jump around, and that is my problem.

[The ORIGINAL work/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/71/)

Comment: You can fadeout all of them and fade in only those required. that way they look synchronized, as required by you.

Comment: IS this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/XzmWV/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qzNEf/5/) :

```
$('#btn-1').click(function(e){       
    $('#cnt-1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#cnt-2').fadeIn('slow');
    });

$('#cnt-4').fadeOut('slow', function(){ 
    $('#cnt-3').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#cnt-6').fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $('#cnt-5').fadeIn('slow');
});

});
```

Did for button `btn-1` alone.

Comment: This looks fine to me! I'll try it with all my buttons! :-) Thank You